# v-btn flickers/blinks on onmouseover/hover

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have several buttons like this ...

```
<v-btn @click="open" class="record" fab light small>
<v-icon  dark>record_voice_over</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

They all flicker/blink when the mouse is over the button. This also prevents clicking.

How do you stop this from happening?  Or how do you disable mouseover/hover on the v-btn?

I'm using lastest CDN version in browser. 
Thanks
Donnie

Comment: if I remove the class="record" and replace it with id="record", the problem is solved.  Guess v-btn doesn't support css classes.

Comment: Is your css scoped?

Comment: No. How does that avoid the flicker?